# Bundle Install Freezes for my Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Occasionally while working with a Rails app, running the `bundle install` command freezes while dealing with the Rails Gemfile. I've tried clearing out the cache to no improvement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be sure to double check and ensure that you're declaring a version of rails. Without declaring a version, the Bundler can end up going in circles trying to evaluate dependencies.

Answering my own question since I found the answer that worked for me.

Comment: +1 - Thank you! This helped me get the issue resolved instantaneously!

Answer (score 3):

i had the same issue, i deleted the Gemfile.lock file and then did 'bundle install' and got it working.
Also, be aware this might update some of the gem versions.

Comment: I faced the reported issue recently after I updated my ruby-version to 2.2.1 from 2.2.0 in my rails app's `.ruby-version` file. My app also used `.ruby-gemset` file. Thus after updating ruby version a new gemset creation was triggered. However running `bundle` freezed after installing few gems. I tried exiting the bundle process and again ran the `bundle` command. However it didn't helped. This I tried multiple times. And I was not having any connectivity issues which might cause this. Finally I ended up on this answer searching for a solution and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: be aware, this solution in most cases will perform updates and install newer versions of gems.

Comment: I have updated my answer adding your suggestion, thanks @DennisvandeHoef