# Can not launch a new project after installing railsinstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, new-project

I just started to learn rails. I am on W8 and I just installed railsinstaller-2.2.2. 
I had no problem during the installation.

Then I tried to build a new project :

```
$ rails new test1
```

And then, it stayed blocked after :

```
   create  test/helpers
   create  test/helpers/.keep
   create  test/integration
   create  test/integration/.keep
   create  test/test_helper.rb
   create  tmp/cache
   create  tmp/cache/assets
   create  vendor/assets/javascripts
   create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
   create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
   create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
      run  bundle install
```

Does anyone have a tips?

I already tried to delete and reinstall railsinstaller. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting specifically? It could be an issue with administrator permissions on W8

Comment: check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997906/bundle-install-freezes-for-my-rails-app

Comment: I do not have any message error ! It looks frozen , but i do not understand the solution in the link @AmrArafat :(

Comment: c:/railsinstaller/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file conftest.exe: Permission denied

Comment: Is that an administrator permission problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try and specify rails version when creating a project. for example:

```
rails _3.2.14_ new test1
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot for explaining the solution !

Comment: In fact, problem wasn't solve. As a Young Padawan I just started the project with an old version (3.2.16). But when I try to do the same with a 4.0.2 vrs, it doesn't work again.

Comment: I have a problem with Installing atomic 1.1.16 : Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Try this, it might work(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461011/new-rails-project-bundle-install-cant-install-rails-in-gemfile)

First uninstall any existing atomic gem:

    "gem uninstall atomic"

Then reinstall it using:

    "gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'"

After this try to create a new rails application:

   "rails new projectname"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed your output, because your output.

```
create  test/helpers
create  test/helpers/.keep
create  test/integration
create  test/integration/.keep
create  test/test_helper.rb
create  tmp/cache
create  tmp/cache/assets
create  vendor/assets/javascripts
create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
run  bundle install
```

Output is looking like that your rails application folder is created properly and ater that your bundle install is running.

please check your folder structure:

```
rails_app_name
..../app
......../controller
......../helpers
......../models
......../views
............../layouts
..../components
..../config
..../db
..../doc
..../lib
..../log
..../public
..../script
..../test
..../tmp
..../vendor
README
Rakefile
```

if rails app folder contain these structure then your app is create properly and your bundle install is taking time.

so, if bundle install taking more time then you can stop bundle install by pressing 'ctrl+c' and try again to install bundle by 'bundle install'