# Error when trying start a local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

Tryed to start a local server ($ rails server) but got this message:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

And when I tryed to run the sudo command I got this message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libkern/OSAtomic.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
atomic_reference.c:57:59: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void **' to parameter of type 'volatile int64_t *' (aka 'volatile long long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h:507:93: note: passing argument to parameter '__theValue' here
bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64( int64_t __oldValue, int64_t __newValue, volatile int64_t *__theValue );
                                                                                            ^
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [atomic_reference.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.16/ext/gem_make.out
```

What can I do?

Comment: I guess you are just starting rails. There is a tutorial "http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#top" that I think will be good for you as a start. Also the first chapter is a guide to install rails correctly along with other things.

Comment: But it worked yesterday and 3 month earlier Amr...

Comment: Rails 4? Did you pull the project from a repo? If the answer is yes to both: it's a common 'issue', with rails 4 the bin path needs to be committed in the repo (it was ignored in previous versions). If that's the case just run bundle --binstubs to regenerate the bins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with Xcode 5.1 updates and Mavericks system Ruby version, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22491165/2271759